# r data.table adjust min and max years only if each set has at least one incrementing obs

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data set that holds an id, location, start year, end year, age1 and age2. For each group defined as id, location, age1 and age2, I would like to create new start and end year. For instance, I may have three entries for china encompassing age 0 - age 4. One will be 2000 - 2000, the other is 2001 - 2001, and the final is 2005-2005. Since the years are incrementing by 1 in the first two entries, I'd want their corresponding newstart and newend to be 2000-2001. The third entry would have newstart==2005 and newend==2005 as this is not apart of a continuous set of years.

The data table I have resembles the following, except it has thousands of entries many combinations :

```
    id    location   start   end   age1   age2
    1     brazil     2000    2000  0      4
    1     brazil     2001    2001  0      4
    1     brazil     2002    2002  0      4
    2     argentina  1990    1991  1      1
    2     argentina  1991    1991  2      2
    2     argentina  1992    1992  2      2
    2     argentina  1993    1993  2      2
    3     belize     2001    2001  0.5    1
    3     belize     2005    2005  1      2
```

I want to alter the data table so that it will look like the following

```
    id    location   start   end   age1   age2  newstart   newend
    1     brazil     2000    2000  0      4     2000       2002
    1     brazil     2001    2001  0      4     2000       2002
    1     brazil     2002    2002  0      4     2000       2002
    2     argentina  1990    1991  1      1     1991       1991
    2     argentina  1991    1991  2      2     1991       1993
    2     argentina  1992    1992  2      2     1991       1993
    2     argentina  1993    1993  2      2     1991       1993
    3     belize     2001    2001  0.5    1     2001       2001
    3     belize     2005    2005  1      2     2005       2005
```

I have tried creating a variable that tracks the difference of the previous year and the current year using lag and then calculating the difference between these two years. I then created the newstart and newend by placing the min start and max end. I have found that this only works if there is a set of 2 in continuous years. If I have a larger set, this doesn't work as it has no way of tracking the number of obs in which the years increase by 1 for each grouping. I believe I need some type of loop.

Is there a more efficient way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### data.table

You tagged with [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table), so my first suggestion is this:

```r
library(data.table)
dat[, contiguous := rleid(c(TRUE, diff(start) == 1)), by = .(id)]
dat[, c("newstart", "newend") := .(min(start), max(end)), by = .(id, contiguous)]
dat[, contiguous := NULL]
dat
#    id  location start  end age1 age2 newstart newend
# 1:  1    brazil  2000 2000  0.0    4     2000   2002
# 2:  1    brazil  2001 2001  0.0    4     2000   2002
# 3:  1    brazil  2002 2002  0.0    4     2000   2002
# 4:  2 argentina  1990 1991  1.0    1     1990   1993
# 5:  2 argentina  1991 1991  2.0    2     1990   1993
# 6:  2 argentina  1992 1992  2.0    2     1990   1993
# 7:  2 argentina  1993 1993  2.0    2     1990   1993
# 8:  3    belize  2001 2001  0.5    1     2001   2001
# 9:  3    belize  2005 2005  1.0    2     2005   2005
```

### base R

If instead you really just mean `data.frame`, then

```r
dat <- transform(dat, contiguous = ave(start, id, FUN = function(a) cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(a) != 1))))
dat <- transform(dat,
  newstart = ave(start, id, contiguous, FUN = min),
  newend   = ave(end  , id, contiguous, FUN = max)
)
# Warning in FUN(X[[i]], ...) :
#   no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
# Warning in FUN(X[[i]], ...) :
#   no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
# Warning in FUN(X[[i]], ...) :
#   no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
# Warning in FUN(X[[i]], ...) :
#   no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf

dat
#   id  location start  end age1 age2 newstart newend contiguous
# 1  1    brazil  2000 2000  0.0    4     2000   2002          1
# 2  1    brazil  2001 2001  0.0    4     2000   2002          1
# 3  1    brazil  2002 2002  0.0    4     2000   2002          1
# 4  2 argentina  1990 1991  1.0    1     1990   1993          1
# 5  2 argentina  1991 1991  2.0    2     1990   1993          1
# 6  2 argentina  1992 1992  2.0    2     1990   1993          1
# 7  2 argentina  1993 1993  2.0    2     1990   1993          1
# 8  3    belize  2001 2001  0.5    1     2001   2001          1
# 9  3    belize  2005 2005  1.0    2     2005   2005          2
dat$contiguous <- NULL
```

Interesting point I just learned about `ave`: it uses `interaction(...)` (all grouping variables), which is going to give all possible combinations, not just the combinations observed in the data. Because of that, the `FUN`ction may be called with zero data. In this case, it did, giving the warnings. One could suppress this with `function(a) suppressWarnings(min(a))` instead of just `min`.

Comment: This would only work if every entry had years incrementing by 1. I only want the min and max years for years that are incrementing by 1... i.e. 2000, 20001, 2002. If the years aren't incrementing in a group, then I want the newstart and newend to hold the original years in the table.

Comment: Fixed, I think that meets it.

Comment: Is it better to use `min`/`max` instead of first/last?

Answer (score 1):

We could use **dplyr**.  After grouping by 'id', take the difference of the 'start' and the `lag`of the 'start', apply `rleid` to get the run-length-id' and create the 'newstart', 'newend' as the `min` and `max` of the 'start'

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
df1 %>% 
   group_by(id) %>%
   group_by(grp =  rleid(replace_na(start - lag(start), 1)),
     .add = TRUE) %>%
   mutate(newstart = min(start), newend = max(end))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 9 x 9
# Groups:   id, grp [4]
#     id location  start   end  age1  age2   grp newstart newend
#  <int> <chr>     <int> <int> <dbl> <int> <int>    <int>  <int>
#1     1 brazil     2000  2000   0       4     1     2000   2002
#2     1 brazil     2001  2001   0       4     1     2000   2002
#3     1 brazil     2002  2002   0       4     1     2000   2002
#4     2 argentina  1990  1991   1       1     1     1990   1993
#5     2 argentina  1991  1991   2       2     1     1990   1993
#6     2 argentina  1992  1992   2       2     1     1990   1993
#7     2 argentina  1993  1993   2       2     1     1990   1993
#8     3 belize     2001  2001   0.5     1     1     2001   2001
#9     3 belize     2005  2005   1       2     2     2005   2005
```

---

Or with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, grp := rleid(replace_na(start - shift(start), 1))
         ][, c('newstart', 'newend') := .(min(start), max(end)), .(id, grp)][, grp := NULL]
```